# Why the first line of the command line is not taken for the output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

```
sed '1d'|awk 'BEGIN{FS=";";sum=0} {sum+=$3; avg=sum/NR; if($3<avg) print $3}'
```

This is the unix command I tried for printing the salary of employees having salary less than the average salary of all the employees. The Input given was:

```
Empid;Empname;Salary
101;V;30000
102;A;45000
103;I;15000
104;S;40000
```

According to the input the average salary= 32500 which means 30000, 15000 both should be displayed in the output. But I can only get 15000 as my output. Please help and tell where am i going wrong.

Comment: At the time you compute `30000 < avg`, `avg == 30000`, not `32500`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F";" 'NR>1 {sum += s[++i] = $3}
    END {avg=sum/length(s); for (i=1;i in s;i++) if (s[i]<avg) print s[i]}' file
30000
15000
```

Also, no need to use both `sed` and `awk` for this. With `awk` you store all salaries, and at the `END` section you compare them with the average.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested based on shown samples. Change `<=` to `<` in case you want to get results only for lesser than average here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=";"
}
FNR==NR{
  sum+=$NF
  count++
  next
}
FNR==1{
  avg=sum/(count-1)
}
$NF<=avg
' Input_file Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                     ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=";"               ##Setting field separator and output field separator as ; here.
}
FNR==NR{                   ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first time Input_file is being read.
  sum+=$NF                 ##Creating sum which is having last field value keep adding to it.
  count++                  ##Increasing count with 1 here.
  next                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
FNR==1{                    ##Checking condition if FNR is 1 the do following.
  avg=sum/(count-1)        ##Creating avg which has division of sum and count-1 here.
}
$NF<=avg                   ##Checking condition if last field is lesser than or equal to avg then print that line.
' Input_file Input_file    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```